# Variable length space using printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to format some printf statements to allow for arbitrary levels of indentation. 
Ideally I want the following output where "One", "Two", etc are placeholders for variable length log messages.

```
One
 Two
  Three
 Two
One
```

I'm working on the variable length spacing required for the indentation, and I know I can do the following:

```
printf( "%*s", indent_level, "" );
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without the second empty string arg.

Answer (score 17):

You can just pass as a parameter what you want to printout:

```
printf( "%*s", indent_level + strlen(mystr), mystr );
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but the output string is also of variable length:
printf( "%*s%d, %d, %d, %s, CONSTANT CHARS, %p\n", indent_level, "", ... );
It's a pain to determine the length of that string without using an intermediate buffer.

Comment: You only have to know the length of the first parameter - e.g. you could use printf("%*d, %d, ...", indent_level, param1, ... )

Comment: I have first time seing that type usage of printf,can you explain why you are using indent_level+strlen(mystr)?

Comment: From printf's manpage: The field width: An optional decimal digit string (with non-zero first digit) specifying a minimum field width. Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the next  argument.

Comment: @adamk Hmm, I don't follow how printf( "%*d", indent_level, param ) will do what I want.

Comment: e.g. if the first parameter is some kind of timestamp (seconds since the epoch), you could write printf("%*d", indent_level + 10, timestamp) - this is because the timestamp is always 10 digits long (at least, for a very long foreseeable future). Of course, if the first parameter is also variable-length, then this won't work for you...

Comment: "Of course, if the first parameter is also variable-length, then this won't work for you" - Yeah, that's the case; it needs to be able to handle a numeric value as the first param.

Answer (score 5):

Can't write a comment for some reason, so posting as a separate necro-answer.

> >> "Of course, if the first parameter is also variable-length, then
>   this won't work for you"
>
> > Yeah, that's the case; it needs to be able to handle a numeric
>   value as the first param.

You can use a dud string

```
printf ("%*s%d", indent_level, "", decimal);
```

in order to indent variable-length decimals. A bit clunky, but works.